# ¿Cómo hacer herencia múltiple en C++?

Tags: c++, herencia, constructor

Estoy trabajando en un código en el cual por motivos de diseño tengo que hacer herencia múltiple, lo que me llevo al llamado **problema del diamante**, aunque en C++ se puede solucionar haciendo herencia virtual, tengo problemas con inicializar el atributo con el constructor parametrizado.

```
// ======== Jerarquia de clases ========

class Base{
    std::string dato_{};
public:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const std::string &dato)
        : dato_{dato}
    {}
    void print() const{
        std::cout<<dato_<<'\n';
    }
};

class Derivada_A : virtual public Base{
public:
    Derivada_A(const std::string &dato)
        : Base(dato)
    {}
};

class Derivada_B : virtual public Base{
public:
    Derivada_B(const std::string &dato)
        : Base(dato)
    {}
};

class Operador : public Derivada_A, public Derivada_B{
public:
    Operador(const std::string &dato)
        : Derivada_A(dato)
        , Derivada_B(dato)
    {}
};

// ======== Fallo al instanciar objeto con herencia multiple ========

int main(){
    Operador operador("Hola Mundo");

    operador.print(); //--> no imprime hola mundo en pantalla

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si pones chivatos en las funciones, verás que no se está llamando `Base::Base(const std::string &)` en consecuencia `Base::dato_` es una cadena vacía:

```cpp
class Base{
    std::string dato_{};
public:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const std::string &dato)
        : dato_{dato}
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\t' << dato << '\n';
    }
    void print() const{
        std::cout << '[' << dato_ << "]\n";
    }
};

class Derivada_A : virtual public Base{
public:
    Derivada_A(const std::string &dato)
        : Base(dato)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\t' << dato << '\n';
    }
};

class Derivada_B : virtual public Base{
public:
    Derivada_B(const std::string &dato)
        : Base(dato)
    {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << '\t' << dato << '\n';
    }
};
```

Con esos cambios [la salida del programa es](https://tio.run/##xVNBT4MwFD6vv@IFEzeSzXmGbYmoix7cjJkHo4Z0pW41pSWl7EL47dgCGyN6mPHgO0D43nvf@95HS5JktCGkLM@YIDyLKEyYTLWiOJ6hFjMIE5sZQoTjNIUApzRHYCLVkefVWYiwlmFe@CjJ1pwRryqwpQMXphDRD5xx7bcokSLVHYZzS@FWFTa8htI@C9TLUa9XVROZaZhMIAwfn25Xq5dw/ry4Xt0vF2Fo4f6b7tu3bau/Rd9HvaLi3UkWQWKmaaOqUpAf5nXI@68HkorVeX8TTq2@QGbJxoobqtgORzi8MnJ3TOkMc6gNaGw6dqOtPmX7yqUa/PvyP0gOfiU5@EfJy4QqHEllJjRCWyeH36Cgu8G@@RT9Rz@omxoeG9Gm8lrleAzTJmCOOZdgLGVmGhaEYQVy/UnNckYAbKmiFoTY3AaWcHroRMicSogxEwM37ygHuV/BuZMcw0MmIum4ZrCt2icvmmPtw3g8Gs1ASGCxwWIKW9sV2y6gAhIstBGJ63ZFdaYEXPqoKMsv):

```
Derivada_A::Derivada_A(const string&)   Hola Mundo
Derivada_B::Derivada_B(const string&)   Hola Mundo
[]
```

Para solucionar este problema, debes traer al ámbito de las clases derivadas el constructor de su base:

```cpp
class Derivada_A : virtual public Base{
public:
    using Base::Base; // Trae el constructor de la base a este ambito
};

class Derivada_B : virtual public Base{
public:
    using Base::Base; // Trae el constructor de la base a este ambito
};

class Operador : public Derivada_A, public Derivada_B{
public:
    using Derivada_A::Derivada_A; // Trae el constructor de la primera base a este ambito
    using Derivada_B::Derivada_B; // Trae el constructor de la segunda base a este ambito
};
```

Con esos cambios [la salida del programa pasa a ser](https://tio.run/##pVJBT8IwFD6vv@IFE2GJOM8bkDiV6EEwBg9GzFK6ijVdu3Qdl4Xfjq/bYBC52UPXff3e9773XlmeD9eM7XYXQjFZphxGQhfWcJpNSIchItR6QgiTtCggpgWvCOAqbBqGzS2k1Oqk2kYkL1dSsLAmOOrAhzGk/IuW0kYdyrQq7InCpZPwa4ZbYSvp9i3xKuJ5NZvp0sJoBEny8vqwWLwn07fZ3eJpPksSB/eXtu@@Lqz5V/2IeNtad6NFCjlms@iqdlAd8p2I9z8OIrVq73Opeo37LcEi21bccyM2NKXJLdrdCGNLKqFpQNumfTe8snA1OjAM3R6dk4n/JTPPuaGpNijSBnf@rv5AcXUyqka4CwjD7hydY8RHjLixEQQwbhdMqZQasA6BXaaKCWpAr344TgUbD9/ccAdChs9C5JIfIgnB8UBGhRr4zXQOden2MOg9aknhuVSp7vmY2LH2l9ftfCMIguFwAiJDIONwHANcQU6VRY@0iTbclkbBDRay2/0C):

```
Base::Base(const string&)   Hola Mundo
[Hola Mundo]
```

Comment: Problema resuelto, aunque sigo sin entender como es que using reemplaza las llamadas a los constructores, es una caracteristica de c++ que no conocia 

Comment: La explicación la ha dado @Mateo en la otra respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

En la herencia virtual, [el constructor de la clase base es llamado directamente](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#virtual-inheritance-ctors). Como en la lista no indicas nada, se llama al constructor por defecto. Deberías escribir lo siguiente:

```
Operador(const std::string &dato)
    : Base(dato), Derivada_A(dato), Derivada_B(dato)
{}
```

Es importante que el constructor de la clase `Base` esté antes que los otros.

Comment: Mateo ¿No es eso un typo?, en el constructor de `Operador` con referencia a cadena estás llamando al mismo constructor `Operador` con referencia a cadena.

Comment: @Paper tienes razón. Gracias